# Why the format via php is not preserved in a selectbox PHP

Tags: php, sql

Hello im trying to achieve this

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jw3-s1j

Actually i think its working fine.. But you CANT difference between a category and a subcategory like in the example before..

So how can i have a select box with a tree inside???

```
<?PHP 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM category")or trigger_error('Query failed: ' . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);; // This line executes the MySQL query that you typed above

$datas = array(); // make a new array to hold all your data


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $datas[] = $row;

}

function generatePageTree($datas, $depth = 0, $parent = 0){
    if($depth > 1000) return ''; // Make sure not to have an endless recursion
    $tree = '';
    for($i=0, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni; $i++){
        if($datas[$i]['parent_id'] == $parent){
            $tree .= str_repeat('-', $depth);
            $tree .= '<option value=\''.$datas[$i]['name'] . '\'>'.$datas[$i]['name'] . '</option><br/>';
            $tree .= generatePageTree($datas, $depth+1, $datas[$i]['id']);
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

echo '<select>';
echo(generatePageTree($datas));
echo '</select>';


?>
```

Solved!!

Fixed Code:

```
function generatePageTree($datas, $depth = 0, $parent = 0){
    if($depth > 1000) return ''; // Make sure not to have an endless recursion
    $tree = '';
    for($i=0, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni; $i++){
        if($datas[$i]['parent_id'] == $parent){
            $tree .= str_repeat('-', $depth);
            $tree .= '<option value=\''.$datas[$i]['name'] . '\'>'.str_repeat('-', $depth).$datas[$i]['name'] . '</option><br/>';
            $tree .= generatePageTree($datas, $depth+1, $datas[$i]['id']);
        }
```

Comment: Try to do it in HTML first (without PHP code!). When it works as you want, you can start writing PHP code.

Comment: i just found the error XD

Comment: Post the solution as an answer in the textbox below, so everyone can see you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

Fixed Code:

```
 function generatePageTree($datas, $depth = 0, $parent = 0){
        if($depth > 1000) return ''; // Make sure not to have an endless recursion
        $tree = '';
        for($i=0, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni; $i++){
            if($datas[$i]['parent_id'] == $parent){
                $tree .= str_repeat('-', $depth);
                $tree .= '<option value=\''.$datas[$i]['name'] . '\'>'.str_repeat('-', $depth).$datas[$i]['name'] . '</option><br/>';
                $tree .= generatePageTree($datas, $depth+1, $datas[$i]['id']);
            }
```